# stacking multiple seaborn.catplot on top of each other

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have multiple different FacetGrid plots using Seaborn (from different dataframes that can't be merged).

Each plot is

```
g = sns.catplot(x="type", y=outcome, 
                        hue="team",
                        order=types
                        ,ci=68.2,
                        kind="point",aspect=1.3,
                        data=df_temp)
```

which will give me 6 of these plots (only two are shown as example)
[image]
[image]

I want to stack them on top of each other to have one single plot with both HH and MH values on the same ax. To get something like this:
[image]

I tried having a `fig = plt.figure()` outside the loop and then `fig.axes.append(g.ax)` inside the loop (over the 6 dataframes) but it didn't work out (I get an empty array in fig.axes)

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: probably something like `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` to be defined outside the loop then plot everything in the same ax ,, `ax.plot(.....)` inside the loop

Comment: but then I can't use `sns.catplot` right?

Comment: Can you share the data by any mean so that we can reproduce the plot?

Comment: @amaatouq yes, but I am not familiar with sns,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing the axis `ax`. `catplot` does not accept `ax` paramater.

EDIT: Based on your own suggestion, `pointplot` works when passed the axis instance `ax`.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

g = sns.pointplot(x="type", y=outcome, hue="team", order=types, 
                  ci=68.2,data=df_temp, ax=ax)
```

Comment: using `sns.pointplot()` worked exactly the way I wanted! update your answer and remove `kind="point",aspect=1.3` and I'll accept it.